# MFC C++ custom control for round gauge

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm hoping here but does anyone have code for a round gauge (like the speedometer in your car) for MFC?

Maybe something exists already but I don't know about it.

I saw an interesting article about making my own customs controls here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521/Creating-Custom-Controls but don't want to spend all day on this, i'm hoping for an easy way out

thanks

Comment: You can search codeguru and codeproject for MFC controls

Comment: sure, did that before i posted here

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about a [CStatic derivative CSpeedoMeter class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9375/CStatic-derivative-CSpeedoMeter-class) on codeproject. Please also have a look at the comments on the article, because some changes to the code might need to be applied in order to fix a resource leak.